# I need to track infos about who download my video contents

Tags: video, mp4

I run a small website with a members area, where members can download videos. I noticed all of my vids are shared as torrent files in the web. Obviously I'd like to stop it, and I had an idea: could it be possible to store some informations in the mp4 file everytime someone is downloading from my website? For example: if John Doe accesses to my Members Area and click on DOWNLOAD button, his IP address is stored in the mp4.

Then I could download my video via a torrent file and check who downloaded.

I don't know if it's possible (well, I think so...) and if it's legal, in terms of privacy.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just repackage the file with a tool like ffmpeg and add whatever medatada you want when the user requests the file.

The user can removed the metadata just as easily though. For a more robust solution you will need forensic watermarking.